# Looking for a term for "not supporting the country you're currently staying in"

Tags: phrases

I remember reading a term(derogatory) which was predominantly used in Britain, if I'm not wrong, that is used to talk about people who have immigrated to Britain but do not support the British sport teams, but instead support the country's team that the person has emigrated from, especially when the particular country is playing against Britain.

Comment: Was it 'traitor' or one of its [synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/traitor.html)?

Comment: Can it be anti-establishment?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an adjective or epithet, but captures the idea:

**(pass/fail the) cricket test**

> British Asian athletes and fans in particular have long been subject
> to racialized nationalist arguments about allegiance and
> assimilation demonstrated through sport team membership/fandom.
> Conservative British politician Norman Tebbit controversially framed issues
> of allegiance and assimilation for British 'immigrants' in terms of a
> '**cricket test**':
>
> "A large proportion of Britain's Asian population fails to pass the
> **cricket test**. Which side do they cheer for? It's an interesting test.
> Are you still harking back to where you came from or where you are?" (April 1990, *Los Angeles Times* interview). [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sport_and_South_Asian_Diasporas/p6bbCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=immigrate%20to%20britain%20but%20cheer%20for%20their%20native%20sports%20team&pg=PT215&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: See also [Cricket test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_test).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. On a separate note, I'm not sure what *harking back to...where you are* means.

Comment: AHD, hark back: *1. To have origin in or be reminiscent of a past event or condition; recall or evoke: songs that hark back to the soul music of the 1960s.
2. To remember or discuss a past event or condition: He's always harking back to his days in the army.*

Comment: @Xanne Yes, that's my problem. I can hark back to to where I came from, but how can I *hark back* to where I am *now*?

Answer (score 0):

The word you seek cannot be 'unpatriotic' since it does not sound neither derogatory or British.
Both NBA-great LeBronJames and now soccer-legend LionelMessi can be considered  'turncoats' (disloyals?) by fanatics. You can always purchase a suffix of choice to make it an adjective...

Comment: “Neither” should be “either” here.